# Constructor not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create custom checkbox with simple title. Checkbox have constructor, but when i call it, the title doesn't appear. How should I call the constructor correctly?

Custom checkbox: https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox

```
import UIKit



class TodoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    //checkbox.titleLabel.text = "asd"
    self.checkbox = M13Checkbox(title: "zcxc")

}

@IBOutlet weak var checkbox: M13Checkbox!



override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: So you can see the checkbox but only the title is missing ?

Comment: Yes, only title don't appear

Comment: Have you tried with setting up the frame or size of checkbox?

Comment: Size changes not working

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have added the M13Checkbox via the Interface Builder so your actual checkbox is set with the `initWithCoder:` method.

I think the simplest way to do that is to remove the checkbox in interface builder and add it to the cell programmatically:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    //checkbox.titleLabel.text = "asd"
    let checkbox:M13Checkbox = M13Checkbox(title: "zcxc")
    checkbox.frame = self.frame
    self.addSubview(checkbox)
}
```

Comment: I think no need of addSubview, if checkbox is already visible. Also addsubview statement written here is in obj-c.

Comment: @Arvind Yep forgot that obj-c code. However i add it to the view because i told him to remove it in interface builder.

Comment: Unfortunately, checkbox don't appears at all

Answer (score 0):

I am not using M13Checkbox myself, but this can't be the intended usage pattern. When you load your UI from the xib, the checkbox should already be instantiated. What you do here, is that you replace it.

Instead, set the correct class in interface builder for the element and only configure its properties as needed. Also, keep in mind that your code does not add any checkbox at all to the view hierarchy, nor does it get any layout constraints.